# Echoing a string into an input field's value attribute only shows partial value?

Tags: php

I'm trying to fetch some data from my database to use in an input field, but it only displays partially.

I've narrowed the problem down to not having anything to do with my database. Simply doing the following only shows "one,"...

```
<input type="text" value=<?php echo "one, two, three"; ?>>
```

When I load the page the input field only has "one," with nothing after the first comma.

However, if I take out the PHP like so, it shows the whole thing...

```
<input type="text" value="one, two, three">
```

I can stick the php code into text areas for instance, and it shows the whole thing as expected, the issue only arrises when I try it in an input field. Any ideas?

Additionally, if I take out the spaces after the commas like so it displays it all...

```
<input type="text" value=<?php echo "one,two,three"; ?>>
```

I am using PHP Version 7.3.5 if this helps at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this code:

`<input type="text" value=<?php echo "one, two, three"; ?>>`

Is the same as:

`<input type="text" value=one, two, three>`

So change your code from:

`<input type="text" value=<?php echo "one, two, three"; ?>>`

to:

`<input type="text" value="<?php echo "one, two, three"; ?>">`

Comment: You're welcome @CraigWilliams , you might want to mark this as correct answer.  Also welcome to Stackoverflow :)

Comment: I had to wait a couple of minutes before I could accept it as the correct answer, but have since done so. Thank you so much!